# 1099 Form-MISC Formatted HTML Form

Tags: html, forms, formatting

Needing to building a HTML form in the format of a 1099-MISC document. I would need to know how to format all the specific boxes that are on the 1099 form itself and have text boxes that would allow for data entry. Given the possible complexity of this task, **where do I start?**

This is for our enterprise content management (ECM) system. Our ECM would place the data into the respective boxes and and then overlay a 1099 form image on top of the entered data, thus filling out the form.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Answer (score 1):

I think we need more information about what systems you are using to make this. Is it pure HTML with nothing else? Any frameworks for the data/model management?

If it's pure HTML and you literally want to "overlay" the boxes on a 1099-MISC *image*, something like a .png, you could start with a  that has the background-image set to the 1099-MISC document image. From there, you would be adding 's inside this parent div with their positioning set to the appropriate place to position them correctly over their respective fields in the 1099.

Each of those 's would likely contain something like an  with the background/borders set to transparent to make them seem like part of the 1099 image.

Comment: Pure HTML, yes. It would be a blank page with text boxes for our ECM to input data and then the ECM would also overlay the image.